# Turkish Character Problem in IE

Tags: .net, asp.net, internet-explorer, character-encoding, character

I just want to get "city" value to a string variable.

But

http://localhost:4928/Default.aspx?method=abc&city=ĞÜŞİÇÖöçşğü

When I type above link to chrome, there is no any problem.
But when I type this link to the IE, it gives me city value as G�SI����sg�

I used 
`<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="tr-TR" uiCulture="tr-TR" />`

and

`<%@ Page Language="cs" codepage="65001" AutoEventWireup="false"CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="getResultFromWS._Default"%>`

And I tried a few way to get correct value of "City"

`StrToEncode = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
 StrToReturn = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Item("city"),System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))` ...

How can I get Correct value(**ĞÜŞİÇÖöçşğü**) of city?It should be UTF-8!

Thx for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the content-type via a meta tag?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```